# In what range is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \Big( \frac{x-2}{6} \Big)^n$ uniformly convergent?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, uniform-convergence

I have this multiple choice question:

> The sequence $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \Big(\frac{x-2}{6} \Big)^n $$
> is uniformly convergent on the interval:
>
> 1. $-6 \leq x \leq 6$
> 2. $-3.8 \leq x \leq 7.8$
> 3. $-8 < x < 4$
> 4. $-4 < x < 0$
> 5. $x \in \mathbb{R}$
> 6. $-7.8 \leq x \leq 3.8$

I have trouble solving this question, because I don't know how to determine the range of uniform convergence. I looked up *Abel's uniform test for convergence*, but this is "only" for determining if a sequence is uniformly convergent, not for determining the **range**. I hope someone can help me with this.

Comment: **Hint :** $\sum z^n$ is convergent if and only if $|z|<1$. It is uniformly convergent on every domain $\lbrace |z|\leq \delta \rbrace$ where $\delta < 1$.

Comment: Perhaps you can consider using the Weierstrass M test? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test#:~:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20the%20Weierstrass%20M,functions%20converges%20uniformly%20and%20absolutely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need $|\dfrac{x-2}6|\lt1\implies |x-2|\lt6\implies  -4\lt x\lt8$.

Thus the answer is $2)$, as we need to restrict ourselves to a compact subinterval.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but I have one question. Doesn't answer 2 ($-3.8 \leq x \leq 7.8$) also satisfy that $|\frac{x-2}{6}|<1$ ? Why can we say for certainty that that is not correct?

Comment: I think, on second thought, that it's $2)$.